# Drupal 7: Can't Update node using php script

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm trying to update a node->body using a php script in my root directory of my Drupal 7.22 installation.
I call the script through a browser (firefox) with [http://MYSITEURL/nodeupdate.php]
But somehow I don't get it to work.
Here is the code I use:

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$nid = 9; // YES node 9 exists.
$node = node_load($nid); // where $nid is the node id

echo "$node->title <br>"; // Just to make sure it changes the right node and it does.

$node->body[$node->language][0]['value']   = "Test updated";

if( $node = node_submit($node)) {
    node_save($node);
    echo "Node with nid " . $node->nid . " updated!<br>";
}

print_r($node); // Check if we see any changes.
?>
```

The script executes fine without any errors. Through the print_r function I can see that the "changed" field and "revision_timestamp" field are changing.
However the body doesn't change!
I have been googling and found many posts from which I gather that this is the way to do it.
What am I missing?

Comment: Just for a sanity check, also run `print(user_access('edit any page content'));`, replacing "page" with the machine-readable content type. It should return 1 (true). Also, is the body not updating when you view the node, or even when you run `print_r($node);` in your script?

Comment: Also, flush your caches just to make absolutely certain there isn't a problem there. There shouldn't be, but let's cover all the bases.

Comment: I'm using my development site so caching is turned off. Nevertheless did a clear cache, no improvement.

Comment: Added print(user_access('edit any page content')); to my script and it returned 1. The node I what to update is a basic page so I didn't change 'page' in the code snipped.

Comment: When viewing the page through the browser will show no updated page. The print_r function doesn't show an updated page also. Invoking the script several times will show only changes in the  [created] => *** [changed] => *** and [revision_timestamp] => *** fields.

Comment: I'm afraid I just can't reproduce the problem then. I tried running your script verbatim (changing only `$nid` to the ID of a test node I created) and it succeeded. Problems with node_save() would be one thing, but as the above code stands `print_r($node)` would reflect the update you made to `$node->body` regardless of any Drupal issues; it's simple PHP. I'm reduced to asking whether the above snippet is a verbatim copy-and-paste of the code you're using, or if there's a typo you're overlooking.

Comment: Two more things to try. First, run `print_r($node);` immediately after updating the body and see if that makes any difference (even though I don't see how `node_submit()` could revert your changes and `node_save()` doesn't pull in your node object by reference anyway). Second, try updating the body the longhand way like this: `$node->body = array($node->language => array(array('value' => "Test updated")));`

Comment: After the $node->body[$node->language][0]['value']   = "Test updated";
I have added:
echo $node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] . "<br>"; This will show "Test updated". However the
print_r($node); will show the old content.

Comment: when using `$node->body = array($node->language => array(array('value' => "Test updated")));` the print_r function gives me .... [body] => Array ( [nl] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => Test updated ) ) ). Both print_r functions before and after the node_submit and node_save. Looks good, but the node doesn't seem to be changed in the browser (after clear cache, clear history). (?)

Comment: Another close examination of the output of print_r when I use the `$node->body[$node->language][0]['value']   = "Test updated";` shows .....[body] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => OLD CONTENT ..... [safe_summary] => ) ) [nl] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => Test updated ) ) ) so here only the safe_summary is updated. Again the same for both print_r functions before and after the node_submit and node_save.
Sorry I missed the last part of the output.

Comment: If I add'$node->revision = TRUE;' to the script I see a Revision added in the browser but no updated body.

Comment: Try printing your arrays and objects inside a <pre> tag, e.g. `echo('<pre>'); print_r($node); echo('</pre>');` This will preserve line breaks and indents in your output and make it much more readable so you'll be less likely to miss values.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're logged into the site as a user with permissions to update the specified content type, because that session will carry over to your bootstrapped script. If you're logged out, you're essentially attempting to update the node as an anonymous user in your script, and permissions will come into play.

Try adding...

```
global $user;
print_r($user);
```

...to your script and see what, if anything, that outputs.

Comment: Did that and the output after login is<br>
... [session] => [roles] => Array ( [2] => authenticated user [3] => administrator ) )<br>
But no change of the body field.

Comment: Refer to my comments on your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved without knowing why.

If I use
`$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']   = "Test updated";`
it works, and if I use
`$node->body[$node->language][0]['value']   = "Test updated";`
it doesn't.

Comment: So for some reason your node's language is set to 'nl' (Dutch?), but it displays the body value under 'und' (undefined and what the `LANGUAGE_NONE` constant evaluates to). So there's probably a discrepancy in your locale or i18n settings, and unfortunately I'm not versed in how those work, but I think that LANGUAGE_NONE is the "safe" option because it will act as the default value if there is no other, or if no other module defines a value for the "current" language.